# nltk: how to search connection between some words?

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I'm using nltk and wordnet to link words which belongs to some group of relations. For example 'parking' and 'building' should have some parent linkage. I use hypernyms but for some words there are no connection.

```
x = wordnet.synset('parking.n.01')
y = wordnet.synset('building.n.01')

print(x._shortest_hypernym_paths(y))
print(y._shortest_hypernym_paths(x))
```

> {Synset('parking.n.01'): 0, Synset('room.n.02'): 1,
>   Synset('position.n.07'): 2, Synset('relation.n.01'): 3,
>   Synset('abstraction.n.06'): 4, Synset('entity.n.01'): 5,
>   Synset('*ROOT*'): 6} {Synset('building.n.01'): 0,
>   Synset('structure.n.01'): 1, Synset('artifact.n.01'): 2,
>   Synset('whole.n.02'): 3, Synset('object.n.01'): 4,
>   Synset('physical_entity.n.01'): 5, Synset('entity.n.01'): 6,
>   Synset('*ROOT*'): 7}

Here, the connection goes through 'entity.n.01' which honestly is the root for almost all physical nouns. How can I get something better than this?

I'd like to get something like 'parking' -> 'structure' -> 'building'; it can be longer but "alien" words shouldn't be up in there, like for example 'monkey' which also zips to entity.

Answer (score 2):

Found some helpful way to view possibilities:

```
def getShortestHypernymPath(word1, word2, nulls=False):
    syns1 = wordnet.synsets(word1)
    syns2 = wordnet.synsets(word2)
    for s1 in syns1:
        for s2 in syns2:
            lch = s2.lowest_common_hypernyms(s1)
            if len(lch) > 0 or nulls:
                print(s1, '<-->', s2, '===', lch)

nlpf.getShortestHypernymPath('parking', 'building', nulls=False)
```

This returns:

> Synset('parking.n.01') <--> Synset('building.n.01') ===
>   [Synset('entity.n.01')] Synset('parking.n.01') <-->
>   Synset('construction.n.01') === [Synset('abstraction.n.06')]
>   Synset('parking.n.01') <--> Synset('construction.n.07') ===
>   [Synset('abstraction.n.06')] Synset('parking.n.01') <-->
>   Synset('building.n.04') === [Synset('abstraction.n.06')]
>   Synset('parking.n.02') <--> Synset('building.n.01') ===
>   [Synset('entity.n.01')] Synset('parking.n.02') <-->
>   Synset('construction.n.01') === [Synset('act.n.02')]
>   Synset('parking.n.02') <--> Synset('construction.n.07') ===
>   [Synset('act.n.02')] Synset('parking.n.02') <-->
>   Synset('building.n.04') === [Synset('abstraction.n.06')]
>   Synset('park.v.02') <--> Synset('build.v.05') ===
>   [Synset('control.v.01')]

so I can at least mediate on it.